# how to replace multiple range of white space with comma in VB?

Tags: vb.net

How do i remove multiple white space with a comma

String str="one     two    "

Need output like str="one,two"

```
                Dim Text As String = str.Trim.Replace("\s{2,}", ",")
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to use regular expressions then you need to use `Regex.Replace`, not `String.Replace`.

Comment: Thank you friend "Regex" doesn't exists in my VB6 but thank you I done by bellow comment.

Comment: What does VB6 have to do with anything?  You tagged the question VB.NET and the answer provided below is specifically for VB.NET.  The `Regex` class certainly does exist in VB.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.Split` and `String.Join` could be used here

```
Dim values = str.Split(new String() { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

Dim result = String.Join(",", values)
```

Answer (score 0):

str = str.trimEnd.replace(" ", ",")